# How can I measure how long this Linux interrupt handler takes to run?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to debug a custom Linux serial driver that is having some issues missing some receive data. It has one interrupt for 4 serial ports, and baud rate is 115200.  Firstly I would like to see how to measure how long the interrupt handler takes.  I have used perf, but things are just in percent and not seconds.  Secondly does anyone see any issues with the below code that can be improved to speed things up?

```
 void serial_interrupt(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    ...

  // Need to loop through each port to see which port caused the interrupt.
  list_for_each(lpNode, &serial_ports)
  {
    struct serial_port_module *ser_dev = list_entry(lpNode, struct serial_port_module, port_list);

    lnIsr = ioread8(ser_dev->membase + ser_dev->chan_num * PORT_OFFSET + SERIAL_ISR);

     if (lnIsr & IPM512_RX_INT)
      {
        while (serialdata_is_data_available(ser_dev)) // equals a ioread8()
        {
          lcIn = ioread8(ser_dev->membase + ser_dev->chan_num * PORT_OFFSET + SERIAL_RBR);

          kfifo_in(&ser_dev->rx_fifo, &lcIn, sizeof(lcIn));

          // Notify if anyone is doing a blocking read.
          wake_up_interruptible(&ser_dev->read_queue);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do these UARTS have receive FIFOs? *"having some issues missing some receive data"* -- Since you always service the UARTs in a fixed order, that's not surprising.   *"any issues with the below code...?"* -- Yes.  For an ISR it does way too much.  It should only fetch (and store) the data, and then schedule a tasklet (just once instead of many times within loops). It's not in kernel coding style.

Comment: Run *IRQ latency* tracer.

Comment: @sawdust I will investigate using tasklets, etc.  Yes the serial ports have each have a 16 byte FIFO, and this interrupt gets called when the FIFO is more than halfway full.  What problems do you see with your first point about always servicing the UARTs in a fixed order?

Comment: *"What problems do you see with your first point about always servicing the UARTs in a fixed order?"* -- Say the 4th port raises its interrupt.  Due to latency, before your ISR can execute, the 1st port also generates its interrupt.  So when the ISR does run, it handles the 1st port.  While that is going on, the 2nd port has an interrupt.  So after the 1st port is (slowly) handled (due to repetitive wake_up_interruptible() calls), the 2nd port is handled.  And then the 3rd port does the same.  Finally when the ISR is ready for the 4th port, its FIFO has been overrun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ftrace API to try to track down your latency issues. It's woth the time to get to know: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt

If this is too heavy-weight, what about adding some simple instrumentation yourself?  `getnstimeofday(struct timespec *ts)` is relatively lightweight... with a little code you could output in a sysfs debug file the worst case execution times, some stats on latency of call to this function, worst-case number of bytes available per interrupt... if this number gets near your hardware FIFO size, you're in trouble.

One optimization would be to read the data in batches into a buffer, as long as data is available, then input the entire buffer, then wake up any readers.

```
while(data_available(dev))
{
  buf[cnt++] = ioread8();
}
kfifo_in(fifo, buf, cnt);
wake_up_interruptible();
```

But execution time of code this simple is not likely to be an issue.  You're probably suffering from missed interrupts or unexpected latency of the interrupt handling.

Comment: Have you heard about *IRQ latency* tracer?